# flot line graphs how do I replace points with icon and remove grid markings?

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm trying to achieve the following in Flot and was wondering if an experienced user could offer some insight.

1. I'd like to replace various plot points with a graphic (not the entire series).
2. I'd like to remove the grid markings.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

1. Sounds very tricky unless you want to hack around with Flot itself / create a plugin
2. Grid lines can be configured using the following option:

   grid: {
       show: false
   }

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to retain the border but remove the grid lines within it. show: false removes the border and x and y values.

Comment: Ah, I see. Bit hacky, but couldnt you set the color of the grid to be the same as the color of the background, and then give the axis and tick marks a different color?

Answer (score 1):

I see it's an old topic but anyway for question #2 options:xaxis{tickLength: 0} and options:yaxis{tickLength: 0} does the job. It's described in the flot's API.txt too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same idea that's used for a tooltip, and make its position be the same as the point itself.  Then the "tooltip" would be an image rather than text.

Example of flot tooltip [here](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/interacting.html).  The example adds 5 to both x and y to avoid obscuring the point, you could remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Flot Symbols plugin](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.symbol.js?r=263). It offers a few new point types (square, triangle, diamond, cross).

Or you can override the callback function and write a little JavaScript to create your own symbol. Someone created a [vector symbol plugin](http://notealso.com/blog/2010/11/14/show-direction-in-the-flot/) that shows the trend of the data:
[image]